# Why does Windows batch file processing exit on IF condition because of a syntax error?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running a batch script that checks the status of a server, and if it's up, it goes ahead and reboots another server.

I put a few PAUSE commands in there because I want to see where it's falling over. It seems do the first ping, and then fail on the IF statement with:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Please can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set ipaddr=10.2.17.24
:loop
set state=down
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set state=up
)
echo.Link is !state!
ping -n 6 10.2.17.24 >nul: 2>nul:
PAUSE
IF "%state%" == "down"
GOTO:loop
else
(
echo.DB server back up
PAUSE
echo.Continuing to web server reboot
PAUSE
set Webipaddr=10.2.17.36
PAUSE
:loop
set Webstate=down
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !Webipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set Webstate=up
)
echo.Link is !Webstate!
ping -n 6 10.2.17.36 >nul: 2>nul:
PAUSE
IF "%Webstate%" == "down"
GOTO:loop
else
echo "Both servers back up."
endlocal
```

Comment: You do not use a colon with `NUL`.  Your `IF ELSE` syntax is incorrect.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?` The help file clearly states the syntax for using `IF ELSE`.

Comment: I cannot see a specific reason to enable delayed expansion.

Comment: There is no need for the `x` in `if "x%%a"=="xReceived"` (empty variables are sufficiently taken care of by the quotes)

Comment: There should be also a space between command __GOTO__ and its argument `loop` or `:loop` whereby the colon is not necessary. `GOTO:loop` also works, but this is just because of automatic error correction by `cmd.exe` on parsing the command line. Run `goto /?` in a command prompt window for help on this command showing also the recommended syntax for using it.

Comment: Windows command processor also does not like labels like `:loop` inside a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)`. The entire command block is parsed before execution of __IF__ command and handled similar to a subroutine. Therefore labels are problematic within a command block. There is no need for an __ELSE__ command block at all. `IF "%state%" == "down" GOTO loop` and removing `else` and `(` is absolutely enough here, especially because of a missing `)` in posted code to finalize the __ELSE__ command block.

Answer (score 1):

On an `if` statements, if you want to write commands with newlines, you need to use parenthesis, like this:

```
IF 1==1 (
  FOO
) ELSE (
  BAR
)
```

So We need to:

- add parenthesis to first IF (before ELSE)
- close the ELSE of the first IF (you seem to be missing a ')')
- the last IF must be fixed to this form: `IF 1==1 (FOO) ELSE (BAR)`

The code, fixed:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set ipaddr=10.2.17.24
:loop
set state=down
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set state=up
)
echo.Link is !state!
ping -n 6 10.2.17.24 >nul: 2>nul:
PAUSE
IF "%state%" == "down" (
  GOTO:loop
) else (
echo.DB server back up
PAUSE
echo.Continuing to web server reboot
PAUSE
set Webipaddr=10.2.17.36
PAUSE
:loop
set Webstate=down
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !Webipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set Webstate=up
)
echo.Link is !Webstate!
ping -n 6 10.2.17.36 >nul: 2>nul:
)
PAUSE
IF "%Webstate%" == "down" (GOTO:loop) else (echo "Both servers back up.")

endlocal
```